# Android developing - connecting tablet through ADB not recognized

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I got a new laptop for development and I've been trying to set up my old eclipse development environment to get going again (oh, the horror!).

Anyways I've been developing on this particular Asus Transformer tablet on my older laptop fine with USB debugging, but now my new laptop won't recognize it. I go to android-sdk/platform-tools, run "adb devices" and get nothing.

I've tried doing "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" but it made no difference.

Anybody able to figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [USB driver](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/#download) for Transformer.

Comment: OK I'll look into that, but I don't recall ever needing one on my old laptop (which was Windows Vista, now I'm on Windows 7)

Comment: What is the result of 'adb devices'

Comment: Usb debugging and Unknown sources all enabled?

Comment: The USB driver is so strange sometimes. I once have a computer (win7 pro), and need not driver; but another computer with also win7 pro needs it. Not only transformer, but also my HTC One.. Anyway, best start is to install it if not working.. also the USB driver from SDK update

Comment: I'm very confused - what do I do after I download the USB driver? It's just a readme and some dll files.

Comment: Install it like other drivers in Windows: right click "My COmputer" -> Manage -> device manager -> other devices (not sure). Most probably you will got an asterisk for that device. Double click and install new driver and search from the extracted driver package folder.